# Why did the delgates show up on different balconies after they signed the Austrian State Treaty?

Tags: austria

One of the most famous pictures in Austria is foreign minister Leopold Figl [presenting the Austrian State Treaty](https://digital.onb.ac.at/rep/osd/?11289F38) at the center balcony of the [Belvedere](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0c/Botanischer_Garten_Der_Universit%C3%A4t%2C_Wenen%2C_Oostenrijk_Aug_02%2C_2019_04-27-11_PM.jpeg/1280px-Botanischer_Garten_Der_Universit%C3%A4t%2C_Wenen%2C_Oostenrijk_Aug_02%2C_2019_04-27-11_PM.jpeg) after it has been signed. Among the delegates in this picture are John Foster Dulles, Leopold Figl, Antoine Pinay, Julius Raab, and Adolf Schärf.

When I searched for this picture online, I also found [this picture](https://digital.onb.ac.at/rep/osd/?10D0763D) showing some the delegates on the balcony of the right end tower. Dulles, Figl and Raab are again on this picture, together with Ferdinand Graf, Harold Macmillan, Vjačeslav Michajlovič Molotov, and Harry Weber.

Why did they appear at two different balconies?

They're roughly the same delegates on both pictures, and the center balcony would have had more than enough space. The center balcony and the balconies on the end tower are all on the same side of the building and can be seen from anywhere in the park where the crowd was.

The "Marmorsaal" (marble hall) in which the treaty was signed is located behind the center balcony and there are several other room between this hall and the rooms behind the balconies of the end towers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked in the contemporary British press for 1955 (sadly I do not have access to that for other countries). I could find a couple of different photographs - probably taken about the same time as your second one, they're on the same balcony, but subtly different in terms of the angles and so on. I guess different agency photographers at different moments.

The caption of the one in the *[Illustrated London News](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/viewer/bl/0001578/19550521/041/0014)* is  interesting (my emphasis):

> After the signing, [the ministers] came out on a balcony of the Palace and were greeted with great enthusiasm. Cheering continued for over an hour, and the foreign ministers and Herr Raab, the Austrian chancellor, were **repeatedly called out**, both singly and together, while flags, handkerchiefs, and hats were waved.

So it seems quite possible that the photos were taken at different points over a period of time, rather than them coming out in one place and immediately going to come out at another. This doesn't explain why they specifically went to different balconies, but it makes it seem a bit less odd.